# Need to escape /> (forward slash and greater than) with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a web page that will display code inside pre tags, and need to render characters used to form HTML tags within those pre tags.  I'm able to escape the greater-than and less-than symbols via jQuery/Javascript per my code below.

However, the combination of a forward slash and a greater than symbol (/>) is problematic. Additionally, I'm getting more expected results rendered in the final output when the page runs.

The contents of the pre tag are simple.

```
<pre>
    <abc />
    <xyz />
</pre>
```

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
    $('pre').html(function() {
        //this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(['/>'],"g"), "#");
        //this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(['/'],"g"), "*");
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(['<'],"g"), "&lt;");
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(['>'],"g"), "&gt;");
    });
});
```

When this runs, what I expect to happen is the page will render the following:

```
<abc/><xyz/>
```

Pretty simple.  Instead, here is what gets rendered in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

```
        <abc>
        <xyz>
</xyz></abc>
```

The tags get duplicated, and the forward slashes get moved after the less-than symbols.  Presently I'm learning jQuery, so there may be something more fundamental wrong with my function.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some invalid HTML. The browser then tries to turn the invalid HTML into a DOM. jQuery then asks the browser to turn the DOM back into HTML. What it gets is a serialisation of the DOM at that stage. The original source is lost.

You can't use jQuery to recover the original broken source of an HTML document (short of making a new HTTP request and forcing it to treat the response as plain text).

Fix the HTML on the server before you send it to the client.

Comment: Thanks Quentin.  I changed the invalid HTML to a couple of break tags, like so: <br/><br/>.  Now the code returns <br><br>.  Why does the ending forward slash in each tag disappear?

Comment: @Ken Palmer I'm going to guess for the same reason as Quentin stated - the browser is parsing your tags before jQuery gets to them. One question: why are you not escaping HTML server side?

Comment: Matt, the output is coming from a flat HTML file sitting on my PC. I'm using it to capture code slices as I work through a textbook to help me retain the material.  Normally that content would be pulled from a database and rendered dynamically via server-side code, where I could perform a replace operation on the HTML before it was sent to the browser.  I'm certainly capable of doing that.  While learning jQuery I thought it would be a reasonable exercise to write a jQuery script that would parse the code slices automatically.

Comment: Maybe there is some jQuery library that already does this, and I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: try @Matt to get my attention. I'm not sure - I think it would need to select the actual DOM nodes and then, based on what type they are, output the equivalent HTML.

Comment: @Matt - I commented out the parsing routine, and used the Google Chrome inspector to view the browser interpreted code.  The forward-slash/greater-than combination gets interpreted by the browser as just a greater-than symbol.  It drops the forward slash.  Along the lines of Quentin's comment, that ill formed HTML gets reinterpreted by the browser.  The browser interprets the text first. So by the time jQuery or Javascript starts pulling the text from the DOM that sits in that PRE tag, that  text has already been reformed by the browser.  jQuery gets it too late.